# i want add value number to first element of of text box

Tags: c#, winforms

```
txtpayAmount.Text = gblFunction.ConvertTwoDecimal(
  txtpayAmount.Text, 
  btn.Tag.ToString(),
  txtpayAmount.SelectedText.Length);

txtpayAmount.Focus();
txtpayAmount.SelectionStart = txtpayAmount.Text.Length;
```

This is my code , am trying to add the value of button to textbox but its adding as last element of textbox.I want to add as first element

Comment: What is `gblFunction.ConvertTwoDecimal`, please? What are the initial values of `txtpayAmount.Text`, `btn.Tag` and `txtpayAmount.SelectedText.Length`? What is the desired outcome and actual one?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly (your question is confusing), you want prepend the text in a textbox.
If you want to do so you can do a `txtBox.Value = 'ValueToPrepend' + txtBox.Value;`